# StartApp StartAppSDK.init(context, appId, enableReturnAds) returns ad

Tags: android, startapp

I am initializing start app ad by following line. Even I passed false in return ad, I see the ad like "You got 1 new app. Click to install".

```
StartAppSDK.init(this, Constants.STARTAPP_AD_APP_ID, false);
```

So how can I disable ad at the time of init ad SDK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
StartAppSDK.init(this, "Your App ID", false);
```

Above statement is enough to disable `return Ad` feature of StartApp.

May be you're are getting `Splash Ad`, which is by default enabled.

You can use `StartAppAd.disableSplash()` that disable `Splash Ad`, after initialisation of StartAppSDK .

Comment: Thank you so much, problem resolved. Along with splash scree, it returns ad after splash screen. Your step resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and even after disabling splash ad the ads were still shown . I solved my problem by just adding `StartAppSDK.enableReturnAds(false);` after initializing the appSDK.